# Instrument string tension calculator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm completely new to Haskell, so please bear that in mind

I'm working on a fairly simple (or so do I think) project - a string instrument tension calculator. Here's what I've got so far:

```
data Operator = Metric | Imperial
  deriving Read

eval o l u p = case o of
  Imperial -> (((2 * l * p)^2) * u) / 386.4

  Metric   -> (((2 * (l * 2.54) * p)^2) * u) / 386.4

prompt txt = do
  putStrLn txt
  readLn

main = do 
  o <- prompt "Metric or Imperial?"
  l <- prompt "Scale length?"
  u <- prompt "Gauge?" -- Unit Weight
  p <- prompt "Pitch? (In hertz)" 
  putStrLn $ "The result is " ++ show (eval o l u p)
```

It lets you choose either Metric or Imperial for your scale length, and calculates the tension based on length, gauge and the desired pitch, giving you an output in pounds.

What I'm having a problem with is: I want the calculator to fetch me unit weight based on the gauge number I input.

I want to change the "u" in

```
  u <- prompt "Gauge?" -- Unit Weight
```

to a "g", and if the "g" matches a number from 0.07 to 0.80, it returns me the unit weight of "u" corresponding to the gauge from a table, for example, the unit weight for a gauge of 0.80 would be 0.00115011, and I want it to be reflected in the equation.

How would I go about that? What do I need to do to create a table/list of the "g" values giving "u"'s?

The table and the equation I'm using, by the way: http://www.daddario.com/upload/tension_chart_13934.pdf

Comment: Note that this kind of task can be done much nicer using a _typed physical quantity library_, such as [units](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/units). Also, I wouldn't write a _program executable_ for such computations, ghci is much more handy – or IHaskell. Here's how it would look for the string-tension calculator: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/leftaroundabout/7a42ac10e89293605f4f18b9ec61b998 (You can freely mix units from different unit systems, and the library automatically performs the right unit conversions. Also it will complain if you enter units whose dimension don't match up.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an hint for a basic solution.

Define your map as a list of pairs `(gauge, unitWeight)`. Make it ordered according to `gauge`.

```
gw :: [(Double, Double)]
gw = [(1, 2), (2, 4), ... ]
```

Then, assume you have a `g` to lookup. You want to discard from `gw` all the initial pairs with gauge `<g`. For that, you can use

```
dropWhile (some predicate here) gw
```

then, you can take the first pair element in the remaining list, and extract the unit weight.

This is not terribly efficient since you scan almost the whole list every time, depending on your gauge. One could improve this with `Data.Map.Map`. Yet, for a beginner exercise, using a list should do. You probably won't have a huge amount of list items anyway, so the program should still be pretty fast.